# Usage of "Hab" during conversations

Tags: verb, colloquial

In school, we learn the conjugations of "haben", but "hab" is not one of them. When is "hab" used and is it colloqial?

Comment: It is common to a lot of languages that speakers tend to swallow end syllables - Same here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Imperative

The form »hab« in fact is an official conjugation of the verb »haben« in standard German. It is one of the two possible versions of the imperative singular (see [»haben« in Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/haben), watch the box on the right). You can use it in sentences like

> Habe Angst! = **Hab** Angst!
>   *Be afraid*! (verbatim: *Have fear!*)

But the most frequent usage is a command that soldiers might hear from their drill sergeants:

> **Hab** Acht!
>   *Attention!* (verbatime: *Have respect!*; »Acht« = old variation of »Achtung« which can mean *attention* as well as *respect*)

This singular version also very often is used if more than one soldier is drilled, but of course there also exists the plural version, which is »Habt Acht!«

---

### Colloquial indicative

But there also is a second usage for »hab«, which is not an imperative, but a colloquial (i.e. non-standard) form of the verb in present tense, singular for the 1<sup>st</sup> person:

> Standard: Ich habe dich lieb. - Colloquial: Ich **hab** dich lieb.
>   The meaning is in the middle between *"I like you"* and *"I love you".* For more details consult the question [What’s the difference between “Ich habe dich lieb” and “Ich liebe dich”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2325/1487).

Since colloquial language almost exclusively exists in spoken language, you hardly will find the colloquial indicative *hab* in written texts. If it is used in written texts, the omitted *e* often (but not always) is indicated by an apostrophe:

> Ich hab’ dich lieb.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, its colloquial and heavily dependent on the region. *Hab* is a sloppy form of

> habe

with the trailing *e* omitted. In writing this is seldom done, and in the rare cases an apostrophe is written instead of the *e*.

For the imperative singular the form *hab* is perfectly legal in addition to *habe* (see [Wiktionary])[1](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:haben), so the *e* never harms.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that no one has mentioned the most common use of `hab` in conversation – when two vowels clash. By far the most common spoken use of `hab` is in `habe es` - `ich hab es getan`, etc

Comment: Which is a colloquial form of the indicative in present tense, singular for the 1st person. Exactly what I described in my answer. But the schwa-sound at the end is omitted also in many other settings: »ich hab geschlafen«, »ich hab keine Angst«, »ich hab mir ein Eis gekauft«, or the example I gave in my answer: »Ich hab dich lieb«. A vowel at the beginning of the next word is nothing special.

Comment: Should I delete this answer?

Comment: This is your decision. If I was you, I would not delete it. Nobody gave -1, but you've got one +1 for this answer (until now). I even think, that most words coming after *hab(e)* really start with a vowel, since it is very often an indefinite article (»*ich hab einen Hund*«), which would make the statement »*the most common use of hab in conversation – when two vowels clash*« right. In my comment I just wanted to show, that this case is nothing special.